# @Retryable doesn't work in spring-data repository interface

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-retry

After I added `@Retryable` annotation to my spring-data-cassandra repository interface, now the application fails to start with following exception:

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

```
The bean 'airingDao' could not be injected as a 'my.dao.AiringDao' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository
```

Action:

```
Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

Added `proxyTargetClass=true` to `@EnableAsync` and `@EnableCaching`, even to `@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass = true)`
`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`

But still doesn't work.

After I remove the `@Retryable`, every thing works fine.

Checked the code, without `@Retryable`, in `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean)`

```
bean.getClass().getInterfaces()
   (java.lang.Class<T>[]) [interface my.dao.AiringDao, interface 
org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, interface 
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy, interface 
org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised, interface 
org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy]
```

So `requiredType.isAssignableFrom(bean.getClass())` is `true`

But after added `@Retryable`:

```
bean.getClass().getInterfaces()
 (java.lang.Class<T>[]) [interface 
org.springframework.retry.interceptor.Retryable, interface 
org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy, interface 
org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised, interface 
org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy]
```

So now `requiredType.isAssignableFrom(bean.getClass()))` is `false` and `getTypeConverter().convertIfNecessary(bean, requiredType)` throws the exception.

Could anyone please help or provide some clue how to troubleshoot it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you using `spring-retry` for?

Comment: I am trying to add @Retryable to save methods in interfaces that implement CassandraRepository. - maybe its not a that valid case :)

Comment: Second approach in Jens Schauder's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42733312/1562662) would be best way you can tackle this. Note that annotating a class/interface using `@Retryable` would add retry to all the methods (public) in it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know Spring Retry, and haven't checked in detail, but I suspect, that there is no integration between Spring Data and Spring Retry yet. If this is true, you have two approaches available to you:

1. Open an issue on Spring Data or Spring Retry to get the integration implemented.
2. Introduce a separate layer for you `@Retry` which you then let delegate to your Spring Data repositories.

Of course those approaches aren't mutual exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround provided. I raised an issue for this in Spring-Retry GitHub.

[Spring-Retry Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/214)